# How do I get Windows to leave the executable bit alone?

Tags: windows, git

I am unfortunately forced to work on a Windows PC part of the time.

When I check out my project, `git status` immediately says:

```
modified:   bin/my_executable
```

`git diff` says:

```
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

"oh, simple" I thought. "Windows just strips the executable bit away."

Now I've been trying to get Git to stop it for the past 30 minutes and I'm about to have a frustration provoked aneurism. Checking out the file doesn't work:

```
$ git checkout bin/my_executable
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Hard reset, no effect:

```
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 789abcd My last commit text
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Switching the executable bit on using `git update-index` doesn't work:

```
$ git update-index --chmod=+x bin/my_executable
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
$ git checkout bin/my_executable
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

Asking Git to kindly ignore the executable bit changes didn't work:

```
$ git config --global core.fileMode false
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
$ git checkout bin/my_executable
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/my_executable b/bin/my_executable
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

This is a complete blocker. Git won't even let me pop my stash without first "committing my changes".

Can anybody help?

Comment: Sorry for not having read accurately enough. I notice you have set `core.fileMode` with the `--global` option here. Is it possible that the local repository configuration is overriding that? It should normally be set per-repo, and changing the global value should normally have little effect.

Comment: @hvd: Yeah, I just checked for that. Turns out somehow `core.fileMode` was set to `true` in the local config. I can't imagine how that happened, I hadn't even heard of the option before today. Un-setting the local option fixed my issue.

Comment: Likely that is because you cloned it on a file system that did support the executable bit, and then moved the entire repository elsewhere. Or maybe you cloned it using an OS that uses OS-specific tricks for the file system to get file permissions working, which (naturally) won't work when another OS then accesses it.

Comment: @hvd: I am synchronizing the repository between a Windows and a Linux system, true, but I've never had this problem before. Presumably, the `core.fileMode=true` setting is implicit on Linux, not explicitly set in the local config?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about it and cannot check right now, but I *think* I recall seeing it set explicitly in config files. But it's not that it'll always be set to `true`: if you clone a repository on Linux on a filesystem that cannot keep track of the executable bit in some manner, you should get it set to `core.fileMode=false` on Linux too, and that might explain why you normally don't have the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After doing:

```
git config --list
```

I noticed that `core.fileMode` was set to true locally. I don't know how that happened, but it probably had something to do with the fact that the project directory is synchronized between a Windows and a Linux PC. I have used this workflow for years without this ever happening, though.

In short, this fixed my problem:

```
git config --unset core.fileMode
```

---

**Edit:** According to the comments to this answer, simply unsetting `core.fileMode` is no longer enough as the default value has been changed to `true`. I can't verify that as I no longer use Windows for development, but if that's the case you can manually set it to false instead:

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

Comment: In my case `core.fileMod` was `false` locally, but this command helped anyway. Thanks.

Comment: at least with current git versions, the default value for `core.fileMode` is `true`, so simply unsetting it does not set it to `false`.  Instead you may need to do something like `git config core.fileMode false`.

Comment: Can confirm that `filemode = false` is normally written into `.git/config` when you clone or init on Windows. (I'm using 2.25.1).

Makes sense cause Windows lacks the executable flag so it can only default everything to 644. I was copying an entire git workspace from Mac to Windows because there were uncommitted files and I was too lazy to clone. `git config core.fileMode false` fixed it, thanks!